# ROS Answers SE migration: SICK LMS5xx

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hello I´m Simona, there is' someone who knows how to use SICK LMS5xx???

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/243328/sick-lms5xx/) by [simo26](https://answers.ros.org/users/27932/simo26/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-09-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

here: http://answers.ros.org/question/86246/how-to-use-lms5xx-in-ros/

---

Originally posted by [Akshay](https://answers.ros.org/users/27941/akshay/) with karma: 16 on 2016-09-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0